# How to render the correct view in the plugins in CakePHP ?

Tags: php, cakephp, methods, namespaces

This is my controller method that I am trying to call and I have edited the routes.php so that it calls it and it finds it.

```
    /**
 * Add method
 * //TODO You can set the company and it works as it is supposed to, but when you have an error regarding the editions not set, you just need to return. This needs to be done later on.
 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
public function add()
{
    parent::_add();
    $this->set('columns', [
        'title' => ['title' => __d('cockpit', 'Companies'), 'label' => 'Company']
    ]);

    $this->set("dataAddUrl", '/customerBehaviors/add');
}
```

I have a problem with rendering the view. 
[image]

When I put inside this method $this->render('add.ctp'); then it renders the right view, in any other case it just doesn't. 
In the error itself it doesn't say it goes to the right route. 
Which is this /srv/www/cemcloud2/plugins/Cloud/src/Template/CustomerBehaviors/add.ctp 
I don't know how to add this so that it goes directly there. 
I want to achieve this without rendering the view using $this->render('add');

We are using both plugins and src directories and in our source directory is the one that I want to inherit from my view. (I believe last sentence doesn't make much relevance to the issue itself).
Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the ctp-file present in that location for sure? Try to debug cake _getViewFileName method by adding debug($path . $name . $this->_ext); just before this line https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/View.php#L1093 Post results here.

Comment: /src/View/View.php (line 1091)

'/srv/www/cemcloud2/src/Template/Plugin/Cloud/CustomerBehaviors/add.ctp'

/src/View/View.php (line 1091)

'/srv/www/cemcloud2/plugins/Cloud/src/View/CustomerBehaviors/add.ctp'

/src/View/View.php (line 1091)

'/srv/www/cemcloud2/src/Template/CustomerBehaviors/add.ctp'

/src/View/View.php (line 1091)

'/srv/www/cemcloud2/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Template/CustomerBehaviors/add.ctp'

The second call should be calling the view that I have set. Why it doesn't ?

Comment: Update: I have a problem with cakePHP debug_kit. 
It doesn't function. 

Confirm you have created the file: "Requests/view.ctp" in one of the following paths:

    /srv/www/cemcloud2/src/Template/Plugin/DebugKit/Requests/view.ctp
    /srv/www/cemcloud2/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/View/Requests/view.ctp
    /srv/www/cemcloud2/src/Template/Requests/view.ctp

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question. Because as stated in the comments to my own question, I have had a problem with cakephp inside Vendor. 
I have deleted the vendor directory and then have once again do composer install, which solved the problem.